# NoMethodError: undefined method `deliver_now'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this in my controller:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.account_activation(@user).deliver_now
    ....
  end
```

And I keep getting this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `deliver_now' for #<ActionMailer::MessageDelivery:0x007ffa6646eb60>
```

Any ideas why it's not finding the deliver_now method?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`deliver_now` has been introduced in rails 4.2.beta2. You are probably using earlier version.

Comment: Ahh that could be the issue I'm using rails (4.2.0.beta1) will try that tonite thanks!

Comment: @Bruno, If this answer fix your issue, you may accept is as a correct answer.

Answer (score 15):

I think it's because it's `deliver` (or `deliver!` for the bang version) and not `deliver_now`.

See [ActionMailer::Base](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html)

Comment: Actually it says quite the contrary: 
`mail.deliver_now # generates and sends the email now`

Answer (score 9):

`deliver` works instead of `deliver_now` for older versions of Rails.